# Form action not working in zend framework main.phtml file

Tags: php, zend-framework, amember

```
**<div>
</div>
<form method='post' action='<?php echo /application/default/controllers/views/certificates.php  ?>'>
<input type='text' id='lon' value='<?php echo $user->login?>'/>
<input type='submit' Name='submit' value='Certificate'/>
    </form>
</div>
</div>**
```

The above code makes form  in the user page, but the form action gives error like, Not found .
So please give some answers to solve this and help me to set form  action to a .php file in zend framework. I'm using wamp server to run this.

Comment: Simply Specify `action="controller/action"` and load your certificates view from that action.

Comment: I had created new file in controller directory and in that created a new class but How to create a view in .phtml file and how to implement form action to a controller file.

Comment: Use `zftool` to do this task.

Comment: This project was already built using zend framework 1,So how can I use zftool with the  existing project.

Comment: Are you working on `localhost` or `hosted server`?

Comment: Im working in localhost wamp server

Comment: `zftool` bundled inside your zend framework in `bin` folder. you can use it from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

aMember route all requests via Front Controller (index.php file). It is not possible to access file */application/default/controllers/views/certificates.php* from web directly. I suggest to put your file certificates.php outside of aMember folder. Then you will be able to submit form to it.

Other option is implement custom controller that will handle such form submit. You can put code of your controller to site.php file
(http://www.amember.com/docs/Site.php_file).

Here is example of code:

```
class CertificatesController extends Am_Mvc_Controller {

    function indexAction()
    {
        //handle form submit here
    }
}
```

Then in form action attribute use this one:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php p(REL_ROOT_URL . '/certificates') ?>">
```

- **REL_ROOT_URL** - constant that have relative url to your current
  aMember installation
- **p** - function that escape string and output it
  within template